# Count number of appearances in JSON data for nested element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

How I can get the appearance of elements in JSON data for nested element?

```
[
    {
            "client":"172.16.109.96",
            "check":
                    {
                            "command":"/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'highestCurrent(scale(vcenter.*.*.*.*.cpu.usage_percent_average, 0.01), 5)'  -w 1 -c 6 -p -6hours",
                            "standalone":true,
                            "interval":5,
                            "name":"vm_cpu_average",
                            "issued":1490774610,
                            "executed":1490774610,
                            "duration":0.142,
                            "output":"CheckGraphiteStat WARNING: No data from Graphite\n",
                            "status":3,
                            "type":"standard"
                    }
    },
    {
            "client":"172.16.109.96",
            "check":
                    {
                            "command":"/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'collectd.*.*.system.memory.used.pct' -w 50 -c 75 -p -6hours",
                            "standalone":true,
                            "interval":5,
                            "name":"mem_average",
                            "issued":1490774614,
                            "executed":1490774614,
                            "duration":0.223,
                            "output":"CheckGraphiteStat CRITICAL: collectd.DEMO.172_16_109_100.system.memory.used.pct is 94.44555555555556 \n",
                            "status":2,
                            "type":"standard"
                    }
    },
    {
            "client":"172.16.109.96",
            "check":
                    {
                            "command":"/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'scale(vcenter.*.*.*.*.mem.usage_percent_average, 0.01)' -w 50 -c 75 -p -6hours",
                            "standalone":true,
                            "interval":5,
                            "name":"vm_mem_average",
                            "issued":1490774614,
                            "executed":1490774614,
                            "duration":0.216,
                            "output":"CheckGraphiteStat WARNING: No data from Graphite\n",
                            "status":3,
                            "type":"standard"
                    }
    },
    {
            "client":"172.16.109.96",
            "check":
                    {
                            "command":"/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'absolute(offset(collectd.*.*.system.cpu.idle.pct, -100))'  -c 7 -p -6hours",
                            "standalone":true,
                            "interval":5,
                            "name":"cpu_average",
                            "issued":1490774613,
                            "executed":1490774613,
                            "duration":0.124,
                            "output":"CheckGraphiteStat CRITICAL: absolute(offset(collectd.DEMO.172_16_109_100.system.cpu.idle.pct,-100)) is 10.585147058823525 \n",
                            "status":2,
                            "type":"standard"
                    }
    }
```

]

I need to count the number of appearances of WARNING and CRITICAL appeared, if it's appeared in **output**(check -> output).

Please excuse if this is a novice question. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the array and check with a regular expression the wanted string. Then count accordingly.

```js
var data = [{ client: "172.16.109.96", check: { command: "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'highestCurrent(scale(vcenter.*.*.*.*.cpu.usage_percent_average, 0.01), 5)'  -w 1 -c 6 -p -6hours", standalone: true, interval: 5, name: "vm_cpu_average", issued: 1490774610, executed: 1490774610, duration: 0.142, output: "CheckGraphiteStat WARNING: No data from Graphite\n", status: 3, type: "standard" } }, { client: "172.16.109.96", check: { command: "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'collectd.*.*.system.memory.used.pct' -w 50 -c 75 -p -6hours", standalone: true, interval: 5, name: "mem_average", issued: 1490774614, executed: 1490774614, duration: 0.223, output: "CheckGraphiteStat CRITICAL: collectd.DEMO.172_16_109_100.system.memory.used.pct is 94.44555555555556 \n", status: 2, type: "standard" } }, { client: "172.16.109.96", check: { command: "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'scale(vcenter.*.*.*.*.mem.usage_percent_average, 0.01)' -w 50 -c 75 -p -6hours", standalone: true, interval: 5, name: "vm_mem_average", issued: 1490774614, executed: 1490774614, duration: 0.216, output: "CheckGraphiteStat WARNING: No data from Graphite\n", status: 3, type: "standard" } }, { client: "172.16.109.96", check: { command: "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'absolute(offset(collectd.*.*.system.cpu.idle.pct, -100))'  -c 7 -p -6hours", standalone: true, interval: 5, name: "cpu_average", issued: 1490774613, executed: 1490774613, duration: 0.124, output: "CheckGraphiteStat CRITICAL: absolute(offset(collectd.DEMO.172_16_109_100.system.cpu.idle.pct,-100)) is 10.585147058823525 \n", status: 2, type: "standard" } }],
    count = {};

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var match = a.check.output.match(/CRITICAL|WARNING/);
    if (match) {
        count[match[0]] = (count[match[0]] || 0) + 1;
    }
});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to count the responses on the frontend?  You can use a regex to parse the json if you'd like.

```
var numMatches = (JSON.stringify(yourData).match(/(WARNING|CRITICAL)/g) || []).length;
```

This should be faster than iterated over each item and running a separate regex on each attribute separately.  So if you are going to be running over a large data set I recommend this over the other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
let critialCount = 0
let warningCount = 0

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(data[i].check.output.indexOf('CRITICAL') > -1) {
    critialCount++
  }
  else if(data[i].check.output.indexOf('WARNING') > -1) {
    warningCount++
  }
}

console.log('Critical count: ' + critialCount)
console.log('Warning count: ' + warningCount)
```

Working example:

```js
const data =[
    {
        "client": "172.16.109.96",
        "check": {
            "command": "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'highestCurrent(scale(vcenter.*.*.*.*.cpu.usage_percent_average, 0.01), 5)'  -w 1 -c 6 -p -6hours",
            "standalone": true,
            "interval": 5,
            "name": "vm_cpu_average",
            "issued": 1490774610,
            "executed": 1490774610,
            "duration": 0.142,
            "output": "CheckGraphiteStat WARNING: No data from Graphite\n",
            "status": 3,
            "type": "standard"
        }
    },
    {
        "client": "172.16.109.96",
        "check": {
            "command": "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'collectd.*.*.system.memory.used.pct' -w 50 -c 75 -p -6hours",
            "standalone": true,
            "interval": 5,
            "name": "mem_average",
            "issued": 1490774614,
            "executed": 1490774614,
            "duration": 0.223,
            "output": "CheckGraphiteStat CRITICAL: collectd.DEMO.172_16_109_100.system.memory.used.pct is 94.44555555555556 \n",
            "status": 2,
            "type": "standard"
        }
    },
    {
        "client": "172.16.109.96",
        "check": {
            "command": "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'scale(vcenter.*.*.*.*.mem.usage_percent_average, 0.01)' -w 50 -c 75 -p -6hours",
            "standalone": true,
            "interval": 5,
            "name": "vm_mem_average",
            "issued": 1490774614,
            "executed": 1490774614,
            "duration": 0.216,
            "output": "CheckGraphiteStat WARNING: No data from Graphite\n",
            "status": 3,
            "type": "standard"
        }
    },
    {
        "client": "172.16.109.96",
        "check": {
            "command": "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'absolute(offset(collectd.*.*.system.cpu.idle.pct, -100))'  -c 7 -p -6hours",
            "standalone": true,
            "interval": 5,
            "name": "cpu_average",
            "issued": 1490774613,
            "executed": 1490774613,
            "duration": 0.124,
            "output": "CheckGraphiteStat CRITICAL: absolute(offset(collectd.DEMO.172_16_109_100.system.cpu.idle.pct,-100)) is 10.585147058823525 \n",
            "status": 2,
            "type": "standard"
        }
    }
]

let critialCount = 0
let warningCount = 0

for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(data[i].check.output.indexOf('CRITICAL') > -1) {
    critialCount++
  }
  else if(data[i].check.output.indexOf('WARNING') > -1) {
    warningCount++
  }
}

console.log('Critical count: ' + critialCount)
console.log('Warning count: ' + warningCount)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array#forEach` to iterate over every `output` entry and look for `warning` or `critical` keywords.

```js
var json = [{client:"172.16.109.96",check:{command:"/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'highestCurrent(scale(vcenter.*.*.*.*.cpu.usage_percent_average, 0.01), 5)'  -w 1 -c 6 -p -6hours",standalone:!0,interval:5,name:"vm_cpu_average",issued:1490774610,executed:1490774610,duration:.142,output:"CheckGraphiteStat WARNING: No data from Graphite\n",status:3,type:"standard"}},{client:"172.16.109.96",check:{command:"/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'collectd.*.*.system.memory.used.pct' -w 50 -c 75 -p -6hours",standalone:!0,interval:5,name:"mem_average",issued:1490774614,executed:1490774614,duration:.223,output:"CheckGraphiteStat CRITICAL: collectd.DEMO.172_16_109_100.system.memory.used.pct is 94.44555555555556 \n",status:2,type:"standard"}},{client:"172.16.109.96",check:{command:"/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'scale(vcenter.*.*.*.*.mem.usage_percent_average, 0.01)' -w 50 -c 75 -p -6hours",standalone:!0,interval:5,name:"vm_mem_average",issued:1490774614,executed:1490774614,duration:.216,output:"CheckGraphiteStat WARNING: No data from Graphite\n",status:3,type:"standard"}},{client:"172.16.109.96",check:{command:"/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sensu-plugins-graphite-1.1.0/bin/check-graphite-stats.rb -h 172.16.109.96:8081 -t 'absolute(offset(collectd.*.*.system.cpu.idle.pct, -100))'  -c 7 -p -6hours",standalone:!0,interval:5,name:"cpu_average",issued:1490774613,executed:1490774613,duration:.124,output:"CheckGraphiteStat CRITICAL: absolute(offset(collectd.DEMO.172_16_109_100.system.cpu.idle.pct,-100)) is 10.585147058823525 \n",status:2,type:"standard"}}],
    obj = {};
    json.forEach(function(v){
      var elem = v.check.output.match(/critical|warning/i)[0];
      !obj[elem] ? obj[elem] = 1 : obj[elem]++;
    });

    console.log(obj);
```